# iosアプリで一部の画面のみ横向きで固定させたい

Tags: ios, storyboard

iosアプリ開発をしており、TOP,MAIN,DETAILの３ページで構成されており、TOPとMAINページは縦方向で固定させ、DETAILページのみを横向き方向で固定させたいと考えております。それは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

UIViewController毎に以下のように2つのメソッドをOverrideすれば可能です。

```
// 自動回転させるか否かを返却
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

// 表示可能な画面の表示向きを返却
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    // 横向き(右)の場合
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
    // 縦向き固定の場合はこちら
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```